# Why doesnt label display when I have two checkboxes ticked?

Tags: javascript, html

JavaScript:

```
 function Checkbox() {
//Deleted parenthesis below, because checked is a property, not a function
var FirstClass = document.getElementById("First-Class");
var Standard = document.getElementById("Standard");

if (FirstClass.checked && Standard.checked) || !FirstClass.checked && !Standard.checked) {
   // document.getElementById("CheckError").textContent = "";
    alert("Please");
}
else {
    document.getElementById("CheckError").textContent = "Please Ensure everything is covered.";
}
```

}
HTML :

```
<header class="main-header">  <!--- Header container for the logo and title test--->
<div class="main-logo"><h2><a href="#"><img src="img/main-logo.png"></a></h2></div>  <!---Railine Logo-->
<h1>ailLine</h1>       
</header>

  <input type="checkbox" id="Standard" name="Type" value="Standard">
<label class="light" for="Standard">Standard</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="First-Class" name="Type" value="First-Class">
<label class="light" for="First-Class">First Class</label><br><br>

<label id = "CheckError"></label>

<p id="total-cost"></p>
<button type = "button" value="checkout" id="checkoutbtn" onclick="Checkbox()" >CHECKOUT</button>




<!------------END OF SECOND FORM--------->
```

Hello guys In here I am trying to make a label display if both checkboxes and if both are empty, how can I do this I made an attempt but nothing happens.

Comment: I would remove the `.checked()` part of the `getElementById` selectors for a start.

Comment: call function as `Checkbox()` not like `Checkbox()()`.

Comment: Hey Andy thanks for the help but still same thing.

Comment: Now that you want the user to choose one, and only one, from the two options, why don't you use a group of radios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Standard" name="Type" value="Standard">
<label class="light" for="Standard">Standard</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="First-Class" name="Type" value="First-Class">
<label class="light" for="First-Class">First Class</label><br><br>

<label id = "CheckError"></label>

<p id="total-cost"></p>
<!-- Assign click event on JS script -->
<button type = "button" value="checkout" id="checkoutbtn" onclick="myFunction(); createcookie(); AdultNumber(); calculateFare();" >CHECKOUT</button>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("checkoutbtn").onclick = Checkbox;

function Checkbox() {
    //Deleted parenthesis below, because checked is a property, not a function
    var FirstClass = document.getElementById("First-Class").checked;
    var Standard = document.getElementById("Standard").checked;

    if ((FirstClass && Standard) || (!FirstClass && !Standard)) {
        // Show the message when only one is checked
        document.getElementById("CheckError").textContent = "Please Ensure everything is covered.";
    }
    else {
        // Set empty string in other case
        document.getElementById("CheckError").textContent = "";
    }
}
```

Now, "FirstClass" and "Standard" variables are boolean, so you don't have to use the .checked property inside the if condition.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but still nothing, I seriosly dont understand why.

Comment: Yes, woyld it be possible for you to show me a fiddle?

Comment: I had to make a change to make it work in jsfiddle, I really don't know why.
I had to assign the event from the Javascript instead the "onclick" HTML attribute in the button tag.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, it only has a little syntax error on this line:

```
if ((FirstClass.checked && Standard.checked) || (!FirstClass.checked && !Standard.checked)) {
```

You were missing some parentheses...

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGPpWG